# Request Feedback Tool Only Showing AD users and Groups

Tags: tfs

I can successfully setup a feedback request but I can only add one stakeholder at a time. I thought I'd setup a TFS group and it would send the feedback request to each of the members of that group. No such luck, turns out the TFS groups don't even show on the list of stakeholders in my setup.

[TFS Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmXKb.png) on the group. Please let me know if you need any other information.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submitted feedback will be sent to stakeholders via email. There's no email address for TFS group, so it is not possible to select TFS groups as Stakeholders.

You need to:

1. Create a group in Exchange or mail-enable an existing group in Active Directory, create one email address for the created group. (Check [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124513(v=exchg.150).aspx) for the details.)
2. Add the created Windows Group to TFS, and grand it with the required permissions. (Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Work/connect/give-permissions-feedback) for the details.)
3. When submit the feedback request, type the group alias created in Step1 and click "Check Name". Then, the group will show up correctly, and requested feedback will be sent to everyone in that group.

Comment: This is annoying but it seems to be the case. I guess I should file a feature request.

Thanks Vicky!

Answer (score 0):

I also tried a lot of ways to add a tfs group to stakeholder, but prove to be no way to add a tfs group, stakeholder can only show windows group. You can click "Browse" to select multiple users at a time or add a windows group to TFS group and then select this windows group.